# Calculate the scattering matrix of a 3-port lumped element network

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, s-matrix-theory, network

I can get S11 and S12 by terminating port 2 and 3 with Z0 and Zr respectively. But when I try to calculate S13 it seems less straight forward. The following is the network, taken from Gao, J. The Physics of Superconducting Microwave Resonators. It is also assumed that the coupling capacitance Cc is small.

[image: 3-port network]

The S-matrix given by the original reference is:
[image]

But the way I calculated it is

[image]

Just to re-type the calculation for easier view:

define $\delta_0=\omega C Z_0$ and $\delta_r=\omega C Z_r$.
Assume $C$ is small so that $\delta_r, \delta_0 \ll 1$.

We have $S_11$ by the usual formula of reflection:

$$S_{11}=\frac{Z_{in}-Z_0}{Z_{in}+Z_0}\approx -j\delta_0/2$$

where $$1/Z_{in}=\frac{1}{Z_0}+\frac{1}{Z_r+\frac{1}{j \omega C}}$$

Then I have $S_{31}$ as

$$S_{31}=\frac{V_3^-}{V_1^+}|_{V_2^+=V_3^+=0}\\
=V_3/(V_1^+)\\
=(1+S_{11})\frac{Z_r}{Z_r+\frac{1}{j \omega C}}\\
\approx j\delta_r
$$

Comment: Can you show your calculations when trying to calculate S13?

Comment: Hi, i added my calculation, as well as the result given in the reference. Thanks.

Comment: Note that we have an [equation editor built into the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) which helps for readability of your post.

Comment: i don't understand why this is marked as off-topic?

Comment: @KyleKanos. any chance we can reopen this question?